# Submitting jquery mobile form with data-ajax="true"

Tags: jquery, mobile

I'm currently trying to build a jquery mobile app. I have a form that point to a results page, on I've attached a function that pulls in some json and calculates a few figures based on what the form submitted. My issue is that when the result pages is displayed it doesnt show the actual calculation results until you refresh the page.

I did some research on why this may happen and found its down to JQM loading the page via ajax. The results page works fine when I add data-ajax="false" to the form however I really want to use the transition effects jqm provide on the results page as at the min its either no effects but the form works or effects and the form does work, surely there must be a way to do this?

results page form :

```
<form action="results.html" method="get" id="calculator" data-ajax="true" data-transition="flip">
```

Then on the results page just before the closing body tag I call this script:

```
$('#resultsPage').live('pageinit', function(event) {
    getFigures();
});


function getFigures() {

    var propertyValue = getUrlVars()["propertyValue"];
    var quoteType = getUrlVars()["quoteType"];

    console.log(propertyValue);
    console.log(quoteType);

    $.getJSON(serviceURL + 'calculator.php?value=' + propertyValue, function(data) {

        figures = data.figures;
        $.each(figures, function(key, val) {

            //console.log(figure);
            //console.log('Key: ' + key + '  Val: ' + val);

            if (quoteType == 'buying') {

                if (key == 'total') {
                    $('#tfoot').append('<tr><th scope="row">' + key + ' </th><td><strong>&pound;' + val + '</strong></td></tr>');
                } else if (key != 'value') {
                    $('#tbody').append('<tr><th scope="row">' + key + ' </th><td>&pound;' + val + '</td></tr>');
                }

            } else {

                if (key == 'total') { // Total is wrong need to filter results from server for quoteType
                    $('#tfoot').append('<tr><th scope="row">' + key + ' </th><td><strong>&pound;' + val + '</strong></td></tr>');
                } else if (key != 'completion' && key != 'coal' && key != 'local' && key != 'landRegistry' && key != 'stampDuty') {
                    $('#tbody').append('<tr><th scope="row">' + key + ' </th><td>&pound;' + val + '</td></tr>');
                }

            }

        });

        $('#value').append('&pound;' + data.figures.value);

    });

    //$('#figureList').listview('refresh');

}
```

Does anyone know how I can use the transition effects and still have a working form?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a validation before the submit of the form where you can keep your logic and then submit the form using ajax, as it would normally do.

Here is an example:
http://shadym.blogspot.in/2011/03/client-side-form-validation-using.html

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use  jquery transistion effects
you can use **data-transition** attribute only

ex. data-transition="fade"